# Regular Expression Negative Lookbehind and Lookahead

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture the price from a string. However, I facing some difficulty in capturing the price group. Below are my sample data and my approach.

**Sample**

```
cash $450
012-6323735 
cash 450
500
```

**Current Approach**

I try using negative lookbehind and lookahead of "-" character

```
(?<!\-)(\d+)(?!\-)
```

**Current Output**

[image]

Do anyone have any idea to capture the price group?

**Desired Output**

> cash $450 (True, Capture Group 450)
>
> 012-6323735 (False)
>
> cash 450 (True, Capture Group 450)
>
> 500 (True, Capture Group 500)

Comment: you can use a word boundary and a possessive quantifier: `\b(?<!-)\d++(?!-)`

Comment: Note that the hyphen isn't a special character and doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Since engine isn't specified, possessive quantifiers are hardly a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tell regex that the value before/after a string of digits must not be a dash, regex engine is happy to use one of the digits in a sequence to satisfy this requirement. For example, it says that `01` is followed by `2`, which is not a dash, so `01` must be what you want to capture; obviously, this is not what you want.

One approach to fix this is to add anchors `\b` before and after the capturing group:

```
(?<!\-)\b(\d+)\b(?!\-)
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/TcRsmo/1)